# How to stop vector addition evaluation?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am using the Quantum Notation package, and I have defined an operator on kets called "quantumnumbers" that basically takes a Slater ket and outputs the quantum numbers in a list. This operator is helpful because it allowed me to define a Coulomb interaction matrix element generator that takes a list as input (doing this as an operator didn't work). Here's how the operator works: 
[image: The "quantumnumbers" operator]

When I apply this ket-to-list operator on a linear combination of kets, Mathematica adds the resulting vectors (lists) together, i.e.:

[image]

So it looks like Mathematica automatically added all the vectors together and I'm wondering how to persuade Mathematica to *not* add them, i.e. to leave this as 2/3{list} + 1/3{list} + ...

Any help is appreciated. I apologize for using images to show code - if I copy paste in here where the Quantum Notation package isn't present, the result is quite clunky.

Comment: Do you know about the use of `Hold[]`?

Comment: `Plus` has the `Listable` attribute which causes this behaviour. The only way to get around this is to either define your own addition operator or your own vector container (I don't recommend changing the definitions of `Plus` or something). If you're not interested in adding vector element wise, you should probably just use a head other than `List`.